# Is there any lite weight open source calendar/notepad tool? similar to rainlendar

Tags: open-source, calendar

Is there any lite weight open source calendar/notepad tool? Which is similar to rainlendar. Thanks.

Comment: Is 9.95 euros really that expensive?

Comment: I want to do a little study on the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know rainlendar, but you might want to consider gdeskcal